# Minikube not starting on Ubuntu, throwing errors

Tags: kubernetes, virtualbox, kubectl, minikube, ubuntu-17.04

I'm running Ubuntu 17.04 (zesty) on a Dell XPS 13 (3854 MB of RAM and Intel Core i5-5200U CPU @ 2.20GHz) and trying to start up Minikube, but I'm getting a couple errors when I try to start it up.

```
➜  minikube version
minikube version: v0.22.3

➜  kubectl version
Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"7", GitVersion:"v1.7.5", GitCommit:"17d7182a7ccbb167074be7a87f0a68bd00d58d97", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2017-08-31T09:14:02Z", GoVersion:"go1.8.3", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
The connection to the server localhost:8080 was refused - did you specify the right host or port?
```

I have VM VirtualBox Version 5.2.0 r118431 (Qt5.7.1). I've checked the BIOS settings and have virtualization enabled.

```
➜  minikube start
Starting local Kubernetes v1.7.5 cluster...
Starting VM...
E1025 09:49:40.206594   22972 start.go:146] Error starting host: Error starting stopped host: Unable to start the VM: /usr/bin/VBoxManage startvm minikube --type headless failed:
VBoxManage: error: The virtual machine 'minikube' has terminated unexpectedly during startup with exit code 1 (0x1)
VBoxManage: error: Details: code NS_ERROR_FAILURE (0x80004005), component MachineWrap, interface IMachine
.

 Retrying.
E1025 09:49:40.207051   22972 start.go:152] Error starting host:  Error starting stopped host: Unable to start the VM: /usr/bin/VBoxManage startvm minikube --type headless failed:
VBoxManage: error: The virtual machine 'minikube' has terminated unexpectedly during startup with exit code 1 (0x1)
VBoxManage: error: Details: code NS_ERROR_FAILURE (0x80004005), component MachineWrap, interface IMachine
```

I've tried some suggests that I've found online, like running `~/rm -rf .minikube/` and trying to start up minikube again. I've tried running `minikube stop` followed by a `minikube delete` and then trying to start minikube again. I've tried specifying the virtualbox driver when starting as well `minikube start --vm-driver=virtualbox`. These aren't working, I still get the same error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This looks like an issue with your Virtualbox installation, have you tried reinstalling it?

```
sudo apt-get purge virtualbox virtualbox-dkms
sudo apt-get install virtualbox-5.1
```

Comment: Yup this was it, removed minikube and virtualbox completely and made sure to install the latest version of each and now it's working - something must have gotten corrupted or installed improperly the first time I tried.

Answer (score 0):

Try to enable virtual box in BIOS system, in my case it resovled problem