# Can't start minikube v1.1.1 on Ubuntu 19.04

Tags: minikube

Problem with starting minikube 1.1.1 on Ubuntu 19.04:

`X Unable to start VM
* Error:         [VBOX_HOST_ADAPTER] start: Error setting up host only network on machine start: The host-only adapter we just created is not visible. This is a well known VirtualBox bug. You might want to uninstall it and reinstall at least version 5.0.12 that is is supposed to fix this issue`

I've seen this question: [How to fix VM issue with minikube start ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52277019/how-to-fix-vm-issue-with-minikube-start)  however I'm running ubuntu 19.04, not OSX. I've also done [Minikube not starting on Ubuntu, throwing errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46934453/minikube-not-starting-on-ubuntu-throwing-errors) a couple of times too.

Now, I've installed the dkms package, I've modprobed `vbox-dkms` into the kernel, UEFI secure boot is set up as part of the dkms installation, but I still can't get minikube to start

Anyone have any ideas where to look next or what the problem might be?

Ps. I'm running virtualbox 6.0.6_Ubuntu r129722

Comment: Which version of VirtualBox are you running?

Comment: It seems your VirtualBox was not installed correctly.
Resinstall your VirtualBox insatnce and reboot your machine.
Use `minikube delete and rm -rf .minikube`
Please use also extended logging to see more details using -v 9. 
To test your minikube please run it without vm driver `minikube start --vm-driver=none`,
Please Share with your findings